# Create Fragment transition like Contacts application?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I'm looking to build a Fragment similar to that in the Contacts application.

How would I replicate the way contact cards fragment slides in from the bottom to the top? I want to be able to pull down from the top to dismiss as well.

[image]